# Can't find self written script

Tags: shell, find

I have a very strange problem here on a Mac with OS X 10.9.2
Some time ago I have written a script (called "whilerub") and placed it somewhere to execute from every directory in my system.
So no matter where I am I can always run the script and it works
Now I would like to change something but I can't find it.
What I tried so far:

```
sudo which whilerub
sudo find / -name "*whilerub*"
sudo locate "whilerub"
```

and I checked every directory in my PATH Variable with for example /opt/local/bin/whi and then TAB to complete

It is also not on a externel device or in the network since it runs without network connection too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have defined an *alias* instead of a script?

Defining an alias

```
# alias r='cd ..'
```

And trying to find it with `which`

```
# which r
```

won't find it:

```
# no r in (/usr/local/bin:/ .....)
```